# Scrolling to a Div by Clicking a Link

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

My code looks like this :

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('href');

    var $id = $(id);
    if ($id.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    e.preventDefault();

    var pos = $id.offset().top;
    
    $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: pos});
});
```

```css
body{
  min-height: 1000px  
}
div{
  min-height: 300px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background: red
}
#section-2{
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#section-1">Section 1</a>
<a href="#section-2">Section 2</a>
<div id="section-1"></div>
<div id="section-2"></div>
```

This works well with `<a href="#secton-1">Section 1</a>`

But i have many different divs on the same page.

URL like this: `<a href="/about/#secton-1">Section 1</a>`
how does it work? can anyone help me? thanks in advance!

Comment: An ID is a unique identifier, so you can only assign an ID once. Therefore, when you target a certain id on a page, there is only one target for it to go to. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you but there is no other way?

Comment: You could make a get/post request and pass the id of the div you wanted, and then use jquery to scroll to that div. There are infinite ways to do this. I'm not sure what you want exactly. Would you mind specifying a preferred method, so I could narrow down the possibilities?

Comment: Yes, i have a site wordpress, i want insert custom link, click to menu link will scrolling to div with animation

Comment: What's the issue with targetting by div?

Comment: sorry, i don't understand your question, the div using id like this `<div id="section-1"></div>`